# Fetch as Google says: "I'm sorry, your browser is not supported."

Tags: google-search-console, fetch-as-google

We built a new website with Vaadin Flow and added it to Google Search Console. We tried using fetch as google. But we get the following error:

> I'm sorry, your browser is not supported

[image]

Comment: `your browser is not supported`... try using a different browser and then run the test.

Comment: What browser are you using when trying fetch as Google?

Comment: Please share the URL of a page that treats like that so I can get into it.

Comment: A screenshot would also help.   That would allow us to see if the error were coming from Google or from your website itself.

Answer (score 2):

That implies that your website will not be letting Google crawl your pages.

Somewhere in your websites code will be a check for browser compatibility. And with that warning message. You want to find that and change things so that Googlebot is not considered an incompatible browser.

Googlebot is based of an old version of the Chrome browser. v41 ish. Maybe your website does not want people on old browsers to look at it?